# For what value of $a>1$ is $\int_a^{a^2}\frac{1}{x}\ln(\frac{x-1}{32})$ minimum?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> For what value of $a>1$ is $\int_a^{a^2}\frac{1}{x}\ln(\frac{x-1}{32})$ minimum?

What is the relation between minimum value and integral?
Appreciate for any suggestions.

Comment: Ignore the fact that you have an integral.  How do you find a minimum value of a function?

Comment: differentiate and find critical points. From the answer below, may be I should use the fundamental theorem of calculus. But the lower bound of the integral is not independent, what should I do?

Comment: Write $
\int_a^{a^2 } {}  = \int_1^{a^2 } {}  - \int_1^a {} 
$ to make the lower bound independent of $a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(a) = \int_a^{a^2}\frac{1}{x}\ln\left(\frac{x-1}{32}\right)dx$$

$$f'(a) = \frac{2}{a}\ln\left(\frac{a^2-1}{32}\right)-\frac{1}{a}\ln\left(\frac{a-1}{32}\right)$$

Now when $f'(a) = 0$, we will have minimum value

Can you proceed?

**EDIT**

Using Leibniz rule

$$\frac{d}{da}\int_{f_1(a)} ^ {f_2(a)} g(a,x)dx = g(a, f_2(a)) \cdot \frac{d}{da}(f_2(a)) - g(a, f_1(a)) \cdot \frac{d}{da}(f_1(a)) + \int_{f_1(a)} ^{f_2(a)} \frac{\partial}{\partial a} g(a,x)dx$$

Since $g(a,x)$ is a pure function of $x$, the third term will vanish and give you the equation I have directly used

Comment: Can we apply TFC when the lower bound is not independent with $x$?

Comment: Yes, please refer to my edit for the full expanded use of Leibniz formula and how I have applied it

Comment: Also please remove the -1 :P